# Showing the closure of a subset in the product topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb R^\infty$ be the subset of $\mathbb R^\omega$ consisting of all sequences that are eventually zero (all sequences $(x_1, x_2,...)$ such that $x_i\neq0$ for only finitely many values of $i$). What is the closure of $\mathbb R^\infty$ in $\mathbb R^\omega$ in the product topology?

Currently, I have:

Let $\mathbb R^\omega$ have the product topology. An open set containing $x$ (in $\mathbb R^\omega$) has the form $\prod_i U_i$ where $U_i$ is open for all $i \in \mathbb N$ and $U_i=\mathbb R$ except for finitely many $i \in \mathbb N$. So any open subset of $\mathbb R^\omega$ that has $x$ in it will intersect $\mathbb R^\infty$.

From there, I don't know how to proceed. Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: think about sequences. For what elements $x$ of $\Bbb R^{\omega}$ can you find a sequence of elements of $\Bbb R^\infty$ that converges to $x$?

I didn't read your question thoroughly enough the first time, so here is what I have to say about that:

You've shown that every non-empty, open subset of $\Bbb R^\omega$ intersects with $\Bbb R^\infty$. Here you could be a bit more explicit and say, for instance, "let $x\in U$, and let $N\in \Bbb N$ be so that $U_i=\Bbb R$ for all $i>N$. Then $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{i-1},0,0,\ldots)$ is contained both in $U$ and in $\Bbb R^\infty$".

Once that's done you're nearly there. Here is a general fact, given a subset of a typical space: the complement of the closure is the interior of the complement. We've shown that the complement of $\Bbb R^\infty$ contains no non-empty open subsets, so the interior of the complement is empty. Therefore the closure is the entire set $\Bbb R^\omega$.

Comment: Would it be the elements of $x$ in $\mathbb R^\omega$ that are eventually 0?

Comment: Those are elements already in $\Bbb R^\infty$, so those are some. However, note that, for instance, $$(1,0,0,\ldots),(1,1,0,0,\ldots),(1,1,1,0,\ldots),\ldots$$ is a sequence of elements of $\Bbb R^\infty$ that converges (prove this) to $(1,1,1,1,\ldots)\notin \Bbb R^\infty$, so that element is in the closure.

Comment: I don't understand how that sequence is in the closure?

Comment: Do you know of a general result that relates the two phrases "closed subset" and "converging sequence"?

Comment: I don't know of one. However, I know from Munkres book that a sequence $x_1,x_2,...$ of points of the space $X$ converges to the point $x$ of $X$ provided that for each neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that $x_n \in U$ for all $n \geq N$. So, points like the ones you described can be shown to be limit points, and those limit points won't be in $\mathbb R^\infty$ but will be in $\mathbb R^\omega$, so the closure of $\mathbb R^\infty$ is $\mathbb R^\omega$?

Comment: @Fred That looks correct to me.

Comment: is there a more generalized way of saying this though?

Comment: Actually, now that I read your question a bit more thoroughly, you're really close to a solution there. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: One last question, how did we show that the complement of $\mathbb R^\infty$ contains no non-empty open subsets and that the interior of the complement is empty?

Comment: Every non-empty open set contains an element of $\Bbb R^\infty$, so there is no non-empty open set contained in the complement. The interior of a subset is the largest open set contained in said subset. Because the only open set contained in the complement of $\Bbb R^\infty$ is the empty set, the interior is the empty set. We showed this by pointing out that every non-empty open set contains a sequence that is eventually $0$.